# "invalid argument type" passing html colour through argument of function

Tags: r, ggplot2

The function is:

```
violin_rating_by_time <- function(df,var,color,title){
        
        label <- df %>%
                filter(!is.na(Decade))%>%
                filter(!is.na(!!as.name(var)))%>%
                mutate(Decade = fct_reorder(factor(Decade),Release.Date))%>%
                group_by(Decade)%>%
                summarise(temp=median(!!as.name(var)))
        
        names(label)[names(label)=="temp"] <- var
        
        plot <- df %>%
                filter(!is.na(Decade))%>%
                mutate(Decade = fct_reorder(factor(Decade),Release.Date))%>%
                ggplot(aes(x=Decade,y=!!as.name(var)))+
                geom_violin(color=!!as.character(color),fill=!!as.character(color),position="dodge",outlier.colour="transparent",alpha = 0.4,draw_quantiles = c(0.5))+
                geom_label(data = label, aes(label = !!as.name(var)),color=!!as.character(color),vjust=-0.4,hjust=0.9)+
                theme_aes()+ 
                theme(legend.position = "NA")  + 
                ggtitle(title)
        
        return(plot)
}
```

I pass arguments into the function (df is just a dataframe Im using, not too important.)

```
violin_rt <- violin_rating_by_time(df=df
                                   ,var="Metacritic.Score"
                                   ,color="#EDDDD4"
                                   ,title="Distribution of MC Scores by Decade")
```

I get the following error message

> Error in !as.character(color) : invalid argument type

its coming from the geom_violin function. when I plot without colour, it works fine.

Thanks!

edit: theme_aes() is function I use for some basic theme arguments in ggplot. its not causing the error.

Comment: Is there a way to run this code without `df`? If not can you share an example, eg by including the output of `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: (I'm sure the details are "not important," but it makes work for everyone else to make us guess what data types it uses and to construct our guess at a stand-in.)

Comment: What's `theme_aes` from?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure root cause, but it works for me if the `!!as.character(color)`'s are replaced with `{{ color }}`.

```
violin_rating_by_time <- function(df,var,color,title){
  
  label <- df %>%
    filter(!is.na(Decade))%>%
    filter(!is.na(!!as.name(var)))%>%
    mutate(Decade = fct_reorder(factor(Decade),Release.Date))%>%
    group_by(Decade)%>%
    summarise(temp=median(!!as.name(var)))

    names(label)[names(label)=="temp"] <- var

  plot <- df %>%
    filter(!is.na(Decade))%>%
    mutate(Decade = fct_reorder(factor(Decade),Release.Date))%>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Decade,y=!!as.name(var)))+
    geom_violin(color= {{ color }},fill= {{ color }},position="dodge",alpha = 0.4,draw_quantiles = c(0.5))+
    geom_label(data = label, aes(label = !!as.name(var)),color= {{ color }},vjust=-0.4,hjust=0.9)+
    theme(legend.position = "NA")  +
    ggtitle(title)

  return(plot)
}
```

Fake data

```
df <- data.frame(Decade = 2000,
                 Metacritic.Score = rnorm(10, 10),
                 Release.Date = 2005)
```

Test

```
violin_rating_by_time(df=df
                                   ,var="Metacritic.Score"
                                   ,color="#EDDDD4"
                                   ,title="Distribution of MC Scores by Decade")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `!!` or `{{`. First, `color` is already a color code passed as character string. So you could simply pass it to the `color` and/or `fill` argument in `geom_violin` as is. Additionally, `!!` will only work within a quasiquotation context, e.g. inside a `dplyr` pipeline:

```r
library(dplyr)
dd <- data.frame(x = 1)

foo <- "foo"

## This works
dd %>% 
  mutate(y = !!as.character(foo))
#>   x   y
#> 1 1 foo

## This does not work
dd$z <- !!as.character(foo)
#> Error in !as.character(foo): invalid argument type
```

Second, when you pass a column name as a character string you could access the column inside a `dplyr` pipeline or inside `aes()` via the `.data` pronoun which is also the recommended way to do so. See [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) and [Best practices for programming with ggplot2](https://fishandwhistle.net/slides/rstudioconf2020/#1).

Making use of the example data provided by @JonSpring:

```r
violin_rating_by_time <- function(df, var, color, title) {
  label <- df %>%
    filter(!is.na(Decade)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(.data[[var]])) %>%
    mutate(Decade = fct_reorder(factor(Decade), Release.Date)) %>%
    group_by(Decade) %>%
    summarise(temp = median(.data[[var]]))

  names(label)[names(label) == "temp"] <- var

  df %>%
    filter(!is.na(Decade)) %>%
    mutate(Decade = fct_reorder(factor(Decade), Release.Date)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Decade, y = .data[[var]])) +
    geom_violin(color = color, fill = color, position = "dodge", outlier.colour = "transparent", alpha = 0.4, draw_quantiles = c(0.5)) +
    geom_label(data = label, aes(label = .data[[var]]), color = color, vjust = -0.4, hjust = 0.9) +
    #theme_aes() +
    theme(legend.position = "NA") +
    ggtitle(title)

}

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(Decade = 2000,
                 Metacritic.Score = rnorm(10, 10),
                 Release.Date = 2005)

violin_rating_by_time(
  df = df,
  var = "Metacritic.Score",
  color = "#EDDDD4",
  title = "Distribution of MC Scores by Decade"
)
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: outlier.colour
```

[image]